# Jquery custom validation messages

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-validate

I'm making a contact form in jquery but I'm having some difficulties showing my custom validation messages. It only shows a tiny popup with the message: "Please fill in the form" and not the custom message I specified. I tried different version of the validation plugin and that didn't work. I followed multiple tutorials all with the same result. Could some of you put me on the right path so I can finish this on my own ?

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#contact_form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "come on, you have a name don't you?"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $(form).ajxSubmit({
            type: "POST",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            url: "",
            success: function () {
                $('#contact_form :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#contact_form').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function () {
                    $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(this).find('label').css('cursor', 'default');
                    $('#success').fadeIn();
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#contact_form').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function () {
                    $('#error').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="contact" id="contact_form">
                    <div class="row uniform collapse-at-2">
                        <div class="6u">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="6u">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row uniform">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row uniform">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6" required=""></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row uniform">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <ul class="actions">
                                <li>
                                    <input type="submit" class="special" value="Send Message" id="submit" name="submit" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form" /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery validation plugin?

Comment: Are you not seeing? 'come on, you have a name don't you?'?

Comment: No... Also like i said above

Comment: The little pop-ups are the default HTML5 validation generated by your browser and have nothing to do with JavaScript or the plugin.  In other words, something in your code is breaking the plugin or you've simply failed to include the Validate plugin.  Refer to your JavaScript error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code seems fine for me. Make sure you've included jQuery main library before all dependent libraries (For eg. autocomplete or other plugins)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>jQuery Autocomplete</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#contact_form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "come on, you have a name don't you?"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $(form).ajxSubmit({
            type: "POST",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            url: "",
            success: function () {
                $('#contact_form :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#contact_form').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function () {
                    $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(this).find('label').css('cursor', 'default');
                    $('#success').fadeIn();
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#contact_form').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function () {
                    $('#error').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" name="contact" id="contact_form">
                    <div class="row uniform collapse-at-2">
                        <div class="6u">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="6u">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row uniform">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row uniform">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6" required=""></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row uniform">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <ul class="actions">
                                <li>
                                    <input type="submit" class="special" value="Send Message" id="submit" name="submit" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form" /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
</body>
</html>
```